# How to break lists in R

Tags: r

How can I break list `x1` below and see output `a` and `b` separately

```
library(parallel)
set.seed(0)
system.time(
  x1 <- parLapply(cl,1:10000,function(i) {
                                          n<-rpois(1,4)
                                          c(a=c(n,rexp(rpois(1,n),rate=0.1)),
                                          b=c(n,rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1)))
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Eventually you want to use `data.frame(a=..., b=...)` instead of `c(...)`.

Comment: @jogo, I was actually going to suggest matching brackets correctly before  moving ahead.

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair the question is not how to match brackets.

Comment: @jogo thanks very helpful

Comment: @HaagenDaz, I'm sure it's not, but using a `data.frame` still won't help you if you continue with the sample code you have so far.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stucture the result of the function. Here is my suggestion:

```
list(a=list(n=n, r=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1)), b=list(n=n, r=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1)))
```

The `n` is not necessary - it can be reconstructed with`length(...)` or `nrow()` if needed. So one can do `data.frame(a=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1), b=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1))`
Here is my suggestion for your code:

```
library(parallel)
set.seed(0)
system.time(
  x1 <- parLapply(cl, 1:10000,
     function(i) {
          n <- rpois(1,4)
          data.frame(a=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1), b=rexp(rpois(1,n), rate=0.1))
     }
  )
)
```

Remark:
`a` and `b` could have different number of elements (depending on the results of the two calls to `rpois(1,n)`). In this case the attempt to construct the dataframe gives an error.

Comment: thanks, how can i get values for `a` only from `x1`?

Comment: `lapply(x1, '[', , "a")` BTW: please edit your question to correct syntax: there is one missing `)` http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36128138/edit